# OData4ObjC without using proxyclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, odata

I am using OData4ObjC, want to know is there a way to add/update/delete an entry in a table without using proxy classes. Just similar way the OData4j for Android does

e.g.,

```
OEntity havinaCola = c.getEntity("Products", 3).execute();
```

I am currently using proxy classes for the same as mentioned below,

```
proxy = [[serviceEntities alloc] initWithUri:@"sampleservices/producer.svc/" credential:nil];
QueryOperationResponse *response = [proxy execute:@"customers"];
NSMutableArray *array = [response getResult];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way to do the same i.e., as mentioned in the book written by Author 'Matthew Baxter-Reynolds' 'Multimobile Development (Building applications for the iPhone and Android Platform)' suggests method how to GET/UPDATE/DELETE/ADD entries.

Hope this is useful.

Thanks